# MySql query WHERE condition slow in large table

Tags: mysql

I have a table (ip2country) of 1.5 million record and I'm executing the following query which takes more than 4 seconds
My table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `ip2country` (
  `beginIPNum` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endIPNum` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryId` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index1` (`beginIPNum`,`endIPNum`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(beginIPNum,endIPNum)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (16777216,16777216) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (251658240,251658240) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (503316480,503316480) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (754974720,754974720) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (1006632960,1006632960) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (1258291200,1258291200) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (1509949440,1509949440) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (1761607680,1761607680) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (2013265920,2013265920) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2264924160,2264924160) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (2516582400,2516582400) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (2768240640,2768240640) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (3019898880,3019898880) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (3271557120,3271557120) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (3523215360,3523215360) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN (3774873600,3774873600) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (4294967295,4294967295) ENGINE = MyISAM)

SELECT beginIPNum,endIPNum,countryId,countryName 
FROM sdportallog.ip2country 
WHERE 2130706433 BETWEEN beginIPNum AND endIPNum
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Are beginIPNum and endIPNum set up as indexes?

Comment: About all you can do is increase mysql's key cache sizes, or shard the table into multiple smaller ones so that the individual table's keys can be cached.

Comment: Just a question concerning the granularity of your data... since it looks like you're just looking for the country given an IP address, do you really need 1.5 million records? That's roughly 1 record per 2500 IPv4 addresses. (EDIT: Just downloaded one. It's ~113,000 records.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT beginIPNum,endIPNum,countryId,countryName 
FROM sdportallog.ip2country            
WHERE beginIPNum  <= 2130706433 AND endIPNum >= 2130706433
```

Comment: There's no real difference between this one and the 'between' version - they're executed the same internally. 'between' is just nice bit of syntactic sugar.

Comment: Exactly, so what can i do to make my query faster?

Comment: Are these columns (biginIPNum and endIPNum) has indexes on it? If yes can you please check the query plan to check if sql engine is performing IndexSeek or IndexScan? Or its just doing flat tablescan?

Comment: Logan F. Smyth=> I set up the indexes but still slow, its 4.675 seconds

Comment: Does SQLEngine performing Index seek on those columns?? Or index scan or table scan? If it's performing scan then you can put table hint (FORSEEK) to use index (though not recommended). Or the best solution to considering table partitioning in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The query optimization is to create a couple of indexes. The following script will create two indexes on the table, one on each field.

```
-- Create index on IPFrom
CREATE INDEX index_beginIPNum
    ON sdportallog.ip2country(beginIPNum)

-- Create index on IPTo
CREATE INDEX index_endIPNum
    ON sdportallog.ip2country(endIPNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with indexes. You can try the following approach:

1. Add partitions
2. Add another column to your table
3. Change query

**Partitions**: Try to add partitions (you can test RANGE and HASH). Right strategy you can choose by your own simply re-creating table and re-executing query. For HASH you can start for example with 10 partitions. For RANGE you can:

- inet_aton(1.0.0.0) ... inet_aton(255.0.0.0). No need to create 255 partitions.
- if for any group too many countries exists per group X.0.0.0 you can try to narrow partitions and divide by X.Y.0.0

**Tables changes**:
I suppose it is good practice to add partitioning parameter as column and index it. But feel free this step.

**Changes related you query**:
you should take about adding filtering on your hash/range values. For example, if you are partitioning by X.0.0.0 you should add something like `where your_added_column = inet_aton(X.0.0.0) and your_base_condition`

Try to play with different partition types, amount of partitions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have done what you said ant its now takes around 1 second (thanks to u) and i have to do it in milliseconds

Comment: As I see you changed your table but didn't change the query. Are you using `between`? Can you post PLAN?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT beginIPNum,endIPNum,countryId,countryName 
FROM sdportallog.ip2country 
WHERE 2130706433 BETWEEN beginIPNum AND endIPNum **LIMIT 1**